# Were/Would be vs Were/Would have been

Tags: difference, conditional-constructions, parallelism

I'm not sure if I'm right but I think that after "were" I should place "would have been" instead of "would be".

- If I were to make this game, it would have been a lot more difficult. It would have had stronger and better enemies.
- If I were to make this game, it would be a lot more difficult. It would have stronger and better enemies.

I was wondering whether it should be:

- If I were to make this game.

Or

- If I were to have made this game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say **If I were to + verb...** to introduce a hypothetical action that is no less possible now than in the past. You say **If I were to have + verb...** to introduce a hypothetical action  that was only possible (in order to have the desired effect) in the past.

You then follow it by some equally hypothetical consequences of that action. If the hypothetical consequences relate to  the present (and possibly also the past and future), you use **would be**. If the hypothetical consequences relate to the past, you use **would have been**.

> If I were to choose a different career, I would be an astronaut. <- present / present
>   If I were to have trained as an astronaut, I would be able to fly to the moon. <- past / present
>   If I were to have trained as an astronaut, I would have flown to the moon. <- past / past

Comment: How about present/past? If I were to choose a different career, I would have been an astronaut?

Comment: No, you can't have a present action that has past consequences.